# dart - mirror - how to know variable name using mirrors

Tags: variables, flutter, dart, reflection, mirror

I am editing my question to fully describe what i need exactly is. I want to create sql query using reflection based on the model/fields as follows.

here method getFieldName() is a dummy sample of my need because i don't know how to implement.

```
import 'package:reflection_test2/common/reflect/Reflector.dart';

@reflector
class Table
{
  int id;
  String name;

    String sql = "SELECT " + getFieldName(name) + " FROM TABLE "
                 "WHERE " + getFieldName(id) + "=" + 1.toString();

  String getFieldName(dynamic field)
  {
    String fieldName = sameWayToGetFieldName(field);
    return fieldName;
  }
}
```

Comment: When you use this call `HowToGetVariableNameUsingMirros(myint)` you pass not a variable but a value that holds this variable. To be more precise you pass a result of expression `myint`. In such way (from the expression result) not possible to get information about the expression itself.

Comment: thanks mezoni, i got. I have edited my question to fully describe what i need exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with `flutter`. Flutter does not allow using `dart:mirror` package. So there is no way to retrieve the variable name.

PS. Why do you need the name of the variable? If you need named numbers, you can use `Map` class.

Comment: i am using reflectable package in flutter and i am able to do something what i need so far. i have edited my question to fully describe what i need exactly is.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the variable in a class then use reflection...Like this

```
class MyClass{
  int myint = 9;
}

void getVariableNames(){
  ClassMirror classMirror = reflectClass(MyClass);
  for(var attribute in classMirror.declarations.values){
    if(attribute is VariableMirror){
      var attributeName = MirrorSystem.getName(attribute.simpleName);
      print(attributeName);
    }
  }
}

main() {
  getVariableNames();
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:** Flutter doesn't support reflection/mirrors yet but you can try this out in dart.
https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflectionmirrors-system

Comment: thanks Josteve for the idea but still don't know how to match this with my scenario and therefore i have edited my question to describe my exact need.